# Replace lambda function with polymorphic member function

Tags: c++, lambda, polymorphism, anonymous-function

I have the following member in a polymorphic class `Parent` and I am looking for a way to replace `foo` by some kind of virtual member `bar`:

```c
void Parent::myFunc() {
    // lots of variables
    // complicated calculations

    while (/* loop condition */) {
        // more variables and calculations

        auto foo = [&](int n) {/* ... */};

        foo(42);
        // want to replace with virtual
        // bar(42);
    }
}
```

The problem I am having is that `foo` captures everything, and I do not know that correct way to grant `bar` the same access.

1. Passing everything to `bar` as parameters would lead to a big parameter list, and does not seem to be an elegant solution
2. I can also turn local variables of `myFunc()` into members of `Parent`, but this would needlessly extend the life times of those variables, especially for the loop variables.

Comment: I do not think what you are asking is possible as lambda function captures symbols from it's enclosing scope statically where as the polymorphic types gets resolved at run-time. You should be looking at alternatives.

Comment: Your design probably needs work, but it's hard to be more specific without details from which to start. Notably missing: what benefit do you hope to gain from using a virtual function?

Comment: @JaMiT My intention is to have a `bar` that 1. Captures local variables of `myFunc` and 2. Is polymorphic. I am actually not sure if using virtual members is the way to do this.

Comment: What about using a functor and making `operator()` virtual? Why do you even want to capture everything for `bar`?

Comment: Is there any reason to have the lambda in your current code other than to show what you wish to replace?  If you call it right away, the captures do nothing…

Comment: @DavisHerring It's provided to other functions as callback.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You’re right to not want to make the locals into members—which would, among other things, lose thread-compatibility.  Since overriding functions can be defined in other translation units, you have to define some sort of interface and call it.

If you want to avoid a long parameter list, gang the arguments into a struct (which might be a protected member type of the base class).  If appropriate, you can even reuse the struct object for each iteration and just update the relevant fields, or make them be references to the appropriate local variables.

You can also, if it works for your derived classes, define several virtual functions to be called with subsets of your currently-captured variables.

In either case, these emulations of capturing would be called from within the real lambda used for whatever purpose (*e.g.*, a callback as mentioned in the comments).

Comment: using a struct as a protected member of the base class negates your first sentence.  however, the OP didn't say anything about threading, so your suggestion is still a good one.

Comment: @jdigital: The *type* would be a member, not the object of that type.  Edited to clarify.